# Rails nested attributes for through model in JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, activerecord

I have three models.  In my Rails app, they look like the below (unnecessary code omitted for brevity):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :schedules
  has_many :payouts, :through => :schedules

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :schedules
end

class Schedule < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :payout
end

class Payout < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :schedules
  has_many :users, :through => :schedules
end
```

It's a typical Rails many-to-many association with a through model.  However, in the front-end, when putting together the JSON to POST to the controller for a user I need to include the user_id which is not created yet.

The JSON looks like this:

```
{
  "user": {
    "schedules_attributes": [{
      "payout_id": 5,
      "user_id": null
    }]
  }
}
```

The problem with the above JSON is that the `user_id` is not set, because it's being created.  How should this be done?

Comment: It's actually about what you have in your controller - can  you add the `create` code?

Comment: In a has_many/belongs_to relationship I just send an array of JS objects in the request body, and ex: 'Record.new(record_params)` works when I permit the nested attributes in the controller.  Can I not do the same thing/would that be why it's not saving properly?

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to create a new user and some associated schedules, then you don't need to specify user_id for a schedule, Rails will set it automatically after creating user record. This is how accepts_nested_attributes_for works.

Comment: So this JSON should set the user_id?

Comment: No, it shouldn't (as there is no user). It is Rails who takes care about settings user_id. Just pass it user parameters with schedules_attributes and it will understand that schedule belongs to user and set user_id.